# Авторизация через соцсети

Tags: авторизация, соцсети

Нужно добавить на сайт авторизацию через соцсети, но для этого нужно зарегистрироваться в необходимых соцсетях и настроить.
Интересует, для регистрации и настройки, т.е. для получения id, к примеру в facebook или google, регистрироваться должен я как разработчик или это нужно регистрироваться самому клиенту?

Comment: Вы должны иметь там регистрацию для того, чтобы иметь возможность добавить туда своё приложение и получить код для вставки на сайт. Пользователь должен быть зарегистрирован там для того, чтобы иметь возможность авторизоваться у вас на сайте.

Comment: @nightflash, вопрос был в том, этот код нужно получать и регистрироваться нужно клиенту или мне как разработчику нужно регистрироваться в facebook и google?

Comment: Разработчику конечно